# Mongodb how to design a structure that one field may ref another collection or may not ref any collection?

Tags: mongodb, schema

Suppose i have company collection, and company has members, members of company may be registered in my application as a user or may be not a registered user. So now how i can store member details such as `first_name, last_name, id of member in case of registered members` inside `company.members`. I have something like this inside company:
[image]

Suppose company has two member: member A is a registered member in my application and i have his/her `id, profilePic`, and member B is not registered, so i have only his/her `first_name, last_name`.

Answer (score 1):

As usual there is more than 1 answer for this question and it depends on how your application will be used, the simplest way is:

1) on company document set a array with your users straight way, this is good for university projects and to proof of concept

In a real world solution I'd split the documents in 2 or more collections, so:

2) on company document set an array with the object id o the user collection, this is useful in case you need to work often with the company or user collection, a separate collection could be used for each registered or unregistered users

3) big trucks need big engine, so if you really need to work hard with company and user documents, like including new user, companies or even changing them from a group to another, registering a new account and them including them to your system in a way often I would suggest using a collection just for the groups

MongoDB does an amazing jog when we talk about reading operation, so the idea is getting its work easier for that, if you split the writing job mongo will work better on that, so managing little chunks of data each time is best

Comment: In case of separate document for registered and non registered company members, the question is in listing of members, how i can apply pagination `limit, skip` and other filters on two separate document ? Because i should bring all member list.

Comment: Nice, your question is getting better because the main goal of a non-relation db is how it reads really fast, so the key is write on it in the best way to be read

So once you need to get those 2 types of documents together and need to compare, limit, paginate and so, I would go to set them to a same collection though, because if you look closer the only difference between a registered and a unregistered member is basically a few properties, or just one depending on how you model them

Comment: In one document, how i can handle `id` of user inside document, because it should reference `user` schema for registered users, but should be empty or may not exist for unregistered users.

Comment: Well, mongodb will create one for you on _id field, but if you like to add another one for your control is up to you, not sure on what exactly you're working on, but if it's not a real world project a good option is setting a boolean field just to say what kind of member is that